# longtable giving erroneous output

Tags: tables, longtable

I need a table that starts right at the point I need it to be and I have no problem if it span across pages. So I have used `longtable` but it is giving erroneous output as shown in photo attached with this question.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Sample Chapter}
        \section{Sample Section}
            \subsection{Chain}
                    \begin{longtable}{|p{.4\textwidth}|p{.6\textwidth}|}
                        %\centering
                        \label{table:chain}
                        \caption{Specifications of Chain Used}
                        %\endfirsthead 
                        \hline
                        Type & Transmission roller chain – British Standard DIN 8187 ISO/R 606\\ \hline
                        ISO Standard & 06 B2\\ \hline
                        Standard Size & $\nicefrac{3}{8}" \times \nicefrac{7}{32}"$\\ \hline
                        Pitch $(p)$ & $9.53mm$\\ \hline
                        Inner Width $(b_1)$ & $5.72mm$\\ \hline
                        Roller Diameter $(D_r)$ & $6.53mm$\\ \hline
                        Pin Diameter $(D_p)$ & $3.28mm$\\ \hline
                        Min. Ultimate Strength & $16.000N$\\ \hline
                        Weight & $0.78Kg/m$ 
                        \\ \hline %
                        
                    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

I am also getting some errors:

> Misplaced \noalign. \caption
>
> Misplaced \omit. \caption{Specifications of Chain Used}
>
> Misplaced \noalign. \hline
>
> Misplaced \omit. T
>
> Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. T

[image: image1]

If I uncomment the `\endfirsthead`, then output is as in second picture.
[image: image2]

One thing to note is that I did not get any output untill I first commented out both `\label` and `\caption`. After first commenting both these gave me correct output without caption, then when I uncommented these it gives this output.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Unrelated, but `\label` should appear after `\caption`, not before; please consider to typeset the various units in your table with `siunitx` as well

Comment: The real error is a missing `\endfirsthead` after `\caption`

Comment: @Thruston Edited the code. Thanks for suggesting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either use a `\endfirsthead`, `\endhead` or just a `\tabularnewline` after `\caption{...}\label{}`,

otherwise `\hline` or any other of the `\...rule` commands do not work, they must start at the beginning of the line, which is not the case without `\tabularnewline` etc.

I also 'slightly' modified the table with `booktabs` and removed the unpleasant vertical lines, as well introduced typesetting of the units with `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo chapter}
\section{Foo section}

\subsection{Chain}
\begin{longtable}{p{.35\textwidth}p{.55\textwidth}}
  % \centering
  \caption{Specifications of Chain Used}    \label{table:chain}
  \endfirsthead
  \toprule
  Type & Transmission roller chain – British Standard DIN 8187 ISO/R 606\\
  \midrule
  ISO Standard & 06 B2\\

  Standard Size & $\nicefrac{3}{8}" \times \nicefrac{7}{32}"$\\

  Pitch $(p)$ & \SI{9.53}{\milli\meter}\\

  Inner Width $(b_1)$ & \SI{5.72}{\milli\meter}\\

  Roller Diameter $(D_r)$ & \SI{6.53}{\milli\meter}\\

  Pin Diameter $(D_p)$ & \SI{3.28}{\milli\meter}\\

  Min. Ultimate Strength & \SI{16.000}{\newton}\\

  Weight & \SI{0.78}{\kilo\gram/\meter}\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Christian Hupfer, you did more than I was expecting.

Comment: @GaurishGangwar: Thanks, you're welcome. Happy TeXing!

Comment: I would remove all `\hrule` commands between ordinary rows and end the table with `\bottomrule` to represent the table much more clearly.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Thanks, it looks better then, I've updated